# Decoding Shape using Arcade in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geometry, arcade

I have Shape column in ArcGIS Pro.

How do I get x,y from it with Arcade?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will show the x and y coordinates (in the layer's coordinate system)

```
var feat = Geometry($feature);
return feat.x + ", " + feat.y;
```